# SQL SELECT query between 2 unknown dates

Tags: sqlite

I was trying to find symptoms between 2 dates. The date is obtained from a table and is not current date. The range is date +1 day to date+ 5 days. I wrote this code but it does not seem to work.

Where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT answer
FROM column
WHERE BETWEEN date(date,'+1 day') AND date(date, '+5 days')
```

Comment: SELECT date
FROM date_list
WHERE ****WHAT**** BETWEEN YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +5 days   Fill in this WHAT please

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score -1):

--maybe like this :)
--dateadd to +5 days

SELECT x
FROM date a
WHERE a.yourDate BETWEEN a.yourDate and DateAdd(day, 5, a.yourDate)

--using GateDate();

SELECT x
FROM date a
WHERE a.yourDate BETWEEN getdate() and DateAdd(day, 5, getdate())

Comment: I tried your method, however I get "ERROR: No such column: day".

Comment: a.yourData (your date column) is datetime or date format??